# Sharepoint Online - How To Prevent Users From Seeing Who A Document Is Shared With

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-online, document

On a SharePoint Online site, if a user clicks the ellipses next to a document name, they get a pop up that shows who the document has been shared with.

[image: Document Shared With]

How can I prevent users from seeing who a document is shared with?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is by design and there is currently no way to set it through the UI interface. Even if the user permission is set to **restricted read**, it can still be seen.
[image]
To address your concern about the situation, we’d suggest you go to [feedback](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472) on this issue, this is the best platform to let us hear from you and make our products and services better for you and others. The more votes, the easier it is to be seen.